# How could I invoke an api without access token in APIM 2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I couldn't find a way to set "Auth Type" when I tried to create api in api-publisher.

Then I have to add Authentication to request header, but for some reason I don't want to set the auth header for my request.

And I found something in APIM Documention that said I should set "Auth Type" to "None", but I could not see this selection in api-creating page (APIM 2.0).

Will be appreciated if there are any help..thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In manage tab, resources are listed like this.

[image]

Here, `Application & Application User` is the default auth type. Click on it and select none.